# Is there any single command or method do determine if a W7 machine is a laptop or a desktop?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, desktop

I'm looking for a command, probably in 'wmic', that will help determine whether a computer is actually a **Laptop or Desktop**.

1. Normally I check in the active directory organizational unit, but
   this is not reliable as there are always errors made by the person
   assigning the OU.
2. Another way that I check is, Start > Run > mblctr.
   If it is desktop it will say that **mobility centre is not available
   for desktops**
3. In My computer properties, under System , Model it is **Notebook PC** . The
   word notebook gives some idea of laptop.

Is There any other way, without using 3rd party software.

Comment: Check if there is a battery installed. Best way.

Comment: @mt025 That is true, but I have seen some desktops showing the battery icon. (but DevMangr will confirm no battery).

Comment: >wmic csproduct.....this will return product information from the bios, which will show product model which makes it easier to determine if it is a laptop or a desktop. But you would have to know your model numbers or google them. What is wrong with your 2 methods that work reliably?

Comment: @Moab ..... Inside WMIC I do 'computersystem get model'  and 'csproduct get name' . Both commands give the same result as my point 3 in my OP. 
What is wrong with my 2 methods that work reliably? Nothing. I just want a definitive method which I can use as a strong artefact.

Comment: @DavidPostill...That VBS is quite bulky even without the select case. I was able to extrapolate a one-liner from that though. It is **wmic systemenclosure get chassistypes**